# Error running Fast RCNN on CPU: Cannot use GPU

Tags: cpu, caffe

I am trying to run Fast RCNN on CPU. I am working with the code I cloned as follows:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn.git

When running py-faster-rcnn/tools/demo.py, I am getting following error:

Warning: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0625 01:37:25.908700 24397 common.cpp:66] Cannot use GPU in CPU-only Caffe: check mode.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted

I have modified the Makefile to use CPU. Have set CPU_ONLY:= 1.
What I am missing here or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing --cpu flag to command line itself i.e. are you running demo.py as follows:
py-faster-rcnn/tools/demo.py --cpu?

If not so, run it with the flag. This error should be resolved with this.